# Load current cache using memoise

Tags: r, memoization, memoise

Let's assume I have run a memoised function that returns an integer output. Now, I do not know what inputs were used to store the current cache. Is there any way that I can get the current integer output that has been cached if using the memoise package?

Below is some minimalistic code:

```
library(memoise)
fn <- function(x) x+5
fn_mem <- memoise(fn)
a <- fn_mem(5)
```

Now assume for some reason, I have lost the variable `a` and don't remember that `fn_mem` was run with input parameter `5` but still need to know what the output was when `fn_mem` was run.

Is it possible to get the currently cached result in such a case?

Comment: Please illustrate your question with some code to make it more precise.

Comment: added code to give perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can define the following function, which takes a memoised function and  returns the result of its last evaluation:

```
getLast <- function(fn){
    stopifnot(class(fn) == c("memoised", "function"))
    keys <- get("_cache", envir=environment(fn))$keys()
    n <- length(keys)
    get("_cache", envir=environment(fn))$get(keys[n])[[1]]
}
```

Example:

```
library(memoise)
fn <- function(x) x*10
fn_mem <- memoise(fn)
fn_mem(1)
[1] 10
getLast(fn_mem)
[1] 10

fn_mem(7)
[1] 70
getLast(fn_mem)
[1] 70
```